# The error CorruptedCacheException keep throwing in Android Studio. What is the solution?

Tags: android, android-studio

> Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 94133 found in cache 'C:\Users\ASUS.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.

Comment: Did it start after a recent update? What changes have you made recently in your And Studio or Project?

Comment: Delete the file-access.bin in path C:\Users(User).gradle\caches\journal-1. After deleting it, Restart Android Studio and rebuilt the project.

Comment: i just download android studio for the first time in my laptop, i try to use AVD that i download recently but that error come when i try to run it, so i check my gradle and download the same version gradle to my android studio i think that's the problem but it doesn't change .

Comment: You are welcome, **Happy Coding!**